# Python, How to do deleting work in a file?

Tags: python, file, io

I know the position of file pointer,and I want to delete the preceding char.

Of course I can create another file,writing in the left content,which is not the way I want.

In other word,I want to do this "inplace".Thank you.

Comment: You'll have to rewrite the file, as the rest of the content in the file has to shift one position up.

Comment: Maybe you want `fileinput.input` with `inplace=True`. But that works on each line

Comment: @jamylak I didn't know the `fileinput` module.Probably it helps.Thx~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for line in fileinput.input('file.txt', inplace=True):
    line = ... # edit line
    print line, # stdout is redirected to the file
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrite the file. Read it into some data format (string or list of strings with `readlines()`) change the char you want and then write the data to the file again. Actually it would be a more sane thing to do than performing a high-precision operation within the file.